# Python property in __init__ with double assignment

Tags: python, properties, init

I have this code:

```
class Human(object):

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self._age = self.age = amount

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, amount):
        if amount > 50:
            self._age = amount
       else:
            print('You are too young')
```

What I am wondering about is, is that a viable way to make the argument passed to `__init__` pass through some sort of logic implemented in the property ? I browsed through a lot of answers here and read the documentation, and still I couldn't find any mention about such a thing. The code is working as intended when creating a test instance of the class:

```
bob = Human(30)
```

yields the proper warning. Attempting to set the name property afterwards does too, and when given a proper argument (in this case any number > 50) everything seems to work as intended. Is there some sort of caveat about this and if yes, what is the most Pythonic way to approach this problem?

Comment: Why not just `self.age = amount` in `__init__`? You shouldn't just `print` if the value is invalid, you should throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ My guess is it's because the OP didn't bother to explain why they're using a double assignment when `self.age = amount` is the obvious way to do this. "Is it a good idea to write needlessly verbose code for an unspecified reason?" isn't exactly a good question.

Comment: With this code, regardless of what the setter for `age` does, `self._age` is going to be assigned the value `amount`. Is that what you want?